# Edit in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am working on Angular 4 project.
Here I want to update the form data using firebase key

I have pass the data through component.ts as follow

```
    this.service.editEnquiry(this.data);
```

I called `editEnquiry()` of service. the `editEnquiry()` is given as follows

```
editEnquiry(data)
{

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.key);    
     this.af.list(`/enquirydata/`+key).update(data);
}
```

I am getting the data in `editEnquiry()`  but its not updating the record in firebase.
Its giving me error like this

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

any help?

Comment: What does your data look like? and what rules you've written for the same?

Comment: data is {key: "-L5OFGaLUXksC7Bla-W7", add: "", college: "", degree: "", degreeyop: "", …}

Comment: You should be passing `key` as separate or construct a new object for data to match data structure.

Comment: Would you mind posting the `rule` for that particular collection?

Comment: then also its not working can you give me the solution plz

Comment: what rules are you asking for

Comment: Firebase rules you have defined in firebase console. You haven't defined any?

Comment: {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}  this rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165699/discussion-between-faisal-amdani-and-guruprasad-rao).

Answer (score 0):

If you updating the data then you need to use -

AngularFireDatabase.object

please try below solution hope it helps -

```
editEnquiry(data)
{

    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.key);    
    this.af.object(`/enquirydata/`+key).update(data);
}
```

Comment: Its adding one field each time its not editing the existing key data

Comment: its giving me like this error Cannot find name 'key'.

Comment: any help please??

Comment: please find below link if am correct - 

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/144

Comment: I have seen it I am not getting from it

Comment: should I pass only key or the whole row data

Answer (score 0):

we have to pass the key and the edited data and the edited function should be like this

```
 editEnquiry(key,value)
{

    console.log(key);
    console.log(value);
this.af.object(`/enquirydata/`+ key).update(value);
}
```

It worked for me